# WSO2 Mobile Device Manager redirection to localhost

Tags: wso2, mdm

here is a brief explanation of my problem :

I am using [WSO2 Mobile Device Manager](https://github.com/wso2/product-mdm) on `local-ip:9443/`

When I try to go to the store and do authentification (`local-ip:9443/store/`) I am being automatically redirected to `localhost:9443/authenticationendpoint/login.do`

Where can I configure the redirection address?

FYI: I was using V1 of WSO2 EMM and I did the same thing by modifying the files below but now I am on V2 :

```
/modules/distribution/src/repository/conf/axis2/axis2.xml
/modules/distribution/src/repository/conf/api-manager.xml
/modules/distribution/src/repository/conf/carbon.xml
/modules/distribution/src/repository/conf/axis2/axis2.xml
/modules/distribution/src/repository/conf/sso-idp-config.xml
```

Answer (score 4):

I found a solution !
To resolve this automatic redirection problem I had to make the modifications below :

> \modules\distribution\target\wso2mdm-2.0.0\repository\conf\carbon.xml

```
...
<HostName>your_server_ip</HostName>
...
<MgtHostName>your_server_ip</MgtHostName>
...
```

> \modules\distribution\target\wso2mdm-2.0.0\repository\conf\app-manager.xml

```
<SSOConfiguration>

    <!-- URL of the IDP use for SSO -->
    <IdentityProviderUrl>https://your_server_ip:9443/samlsso</IdentityProviderUrl>

    <Configurators>
        <Configurator>
            <name>wso2is</name>
            <version>5.0.0</version>
            <providerClass>org.wso2.carbon.appmgt.impl.idp.sso.configurator.IS500SAMLSSOConfigurator</providerClass>
            <parameters>
                <providerURL>https://your_server_ip:9443</providerURL>
                <username>admin</username>
                <password>admin</password>
            </parameters>
        </Configurator>
    </Configurators>

</SSOConfiguration>
```

> \modules\distribution\target\wso2mdm-2.0.0\repository\conf\api-manager.xml

Whenever you find `${carbon.local.ip}` change it by `your_server_ip`

> \modules\distribution\target\wso2mdm-2.0.0\repository\conf\identity\sso-idp-config.xml

Change every `localhost` by `your_server_ip`

> \modules\distribution\target\wso2mdm-2.0.0\repository\conf\identity\identity.xml

```
<ThriftHostName>your_server_ip/ThriftHostName>
```